# CSS horizontal menu with sub options

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add sub menu under main menu items but failed to do so. I've added `display:none` to hide sub menu, `display:block` to show when mouse is over main menu etc to some of the tags in CSS but none of them worked. Perhaps I added to wrong places.

I've cleared all my faulty codes not to deal with messy code instead giving you clear one to modify it.

Sub menu shouldn't be visible unless mouse is over its parent menu. Also sub menu should appear right under its parent menu.

Thanks in advance

**CSS**

```
<style>
.menu{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666666; }
.menu ul{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: left;}

.menu ul li{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;}

.menu ul li a{
    float: left; text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
    padding: 10.5px 11px;
    background-color: #333; }

.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#0b75b2;}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home short</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home very long</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ADMINISTRATOR</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Admin short</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">STAFF</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">staff</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br style="clear:left"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `.menu ul li ul{
    position: absolute;}`

If I understand your problem correctly, works fine now.

so..

```
.menu ul li ul{
position:absolute;
margin-top:40px;
width:150px;}

.menu ul li ul li{
display:block;}
```

To hide until hover, `.menu ul li ul{ display:none; } .menu ul li:hover ul{display:block; }`

Comment: Sub menu shouldn't be visible unless mouse is over its parent menu. Also sub menu should appear right under its parent menu.

Comment: Thanks. Nearly there but sub menu doesn't appear right under its parent menu.

Comment: `position:absolute` would **complicate things further**. A simple float to all the list items should solve this. Well obviously with margins.